# How replace setSupportActionBar by styles?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androidx

In my android app, I can't use AppCompatActivity. 
I have no source code of this part of the project.
So I use

```
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
```

app theme:

```
<style name="MainAppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

my layout with toolbar:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tool_bar_height"/>
        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>    

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
public class MainNavigationDrawerFragmentActivity extends androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
toolbaTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbaTitleTextView);
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this,
    mDrawerLayout,
    mToolbar, 
    R.string.application_name,
    R.string.application_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            toolbaTitleTextView.setText(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
```

as result toolbar is show but menu not show.
To show the menu I need to use

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

but I can't use this method, because I can't use `AppCompatActivity`.

Is it possible to replace `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` by another method or maybe settings/styles to show menu it toolbar?

Comment: If you define toolbar in your xml files then only you have to use setSupportActionBar(toolbar) method otherwise a default toolbar is provided.

Comment: You can try and use `setActionBar` instead.

Comment: Why it is not allowed using AppCompactActivity maybe we can help you by this issue?

Comment: @Jasurbek I has not source code of this part of project

Comment: How you are going to set ToolBar then, if you do not have the source code

Comment: @NovoLucas because setActionBar use android.widget.Toolbar. But in my case I has androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar